# Converting to RESTCLIENT with Ruby

Tags: ruby, rest-client, postman

How can i convert this to RESTCLIENT in Ruby.

Here i am passing below details when working with POSTMAN (Rest Client App for Chrome):

```
URL as : http://localhost:8080/myapplication/api/sites/
Headers as : Content-Type application/json
Data as : {"siteName":"test_site7"}
```

Result successful:

```
{
"success": {
    "body": {
        "id": 17500,
        "siteName": "test8"
    }
}
}
```

How should i do this in RESTCLIENT:

I did some thing like this, but it is not working:

```
response=JSON.parse(RestClient.put("#{HOST}/sites", {siteName:"#{site_name}"}, :content_type => :json, :accept => :json))
```

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? It stops without an error? It runs but doesn't do what you expected? It returns an exception and exits?

Comment: Does the :json symbol have a special meaning? I can't see anything about it in the RestClient or MimeTypes docs. RestClient expects MIME types as strings, not symbols; have you tried :accept => 'application/json' (or accept: 'application/json')?